# SQL Table Constraint to prevent column totals exceeding 100

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

I have a table which contains columns like this:

- SomeId, Int PK
- Item1Weighting, Int
- Item2Weighting, Int
- Item3Weighting, Int

I want to add a constraint to the table that prevents the total of the three "weighting" columns on a single row exceeding a total value of 100.

I've done quite a bit of searching and can't find any help so any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Thanks
Kev

Comment: You could do this with a trigger. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You may define a trigger for INSERT or UPDATE to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this declaratively without resorting to triggers.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
SomeId  Int PRIMARY KEY,
Item1Weighting  Int,
Item2Weighting  Int,
Item3Weighting  Int,
CONSTRAINT CK_WeightingNotOver100 
    CHECK ((ISNULL(Item1Weighting,0) + 
            ISNULL(Item2Weighting,0) + 
            ISNULL(Item3Weighting,0)) <= 100)
)
```

Or to add it retrospectively to an existing table

```
ALTER TABLE T
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_WeightingNotOver100 
    CHECK ((ISNULL(Item1Weighting,0) + 
            ISNULL(Item2Weighting,0) + 
            ISNULL(Item3Weighting,0)) <= 100)
```